# jQuery validator errorplacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My jQuery has the following code:

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).addClass('errorImage').removeClass(validClass).removeClass('validImage');
            if($(element.form).find("input[type=radio") == true) {
                $(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass).addClass('errorImageRadio');  
            }else{
                $(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass).addClass('errorImage');
            }
            },
```

What I am trying is, if the input type is radio or checkbox, it should basically use a different class, I am missing something here, not sure what is that.

It is a part of jQuery validator plugin .

Comment: Simply use  `$(element)` instead of `$(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery objects are always truthy, if you want to test whether the jQuery objects matches any DOM elements, use the `.length` property.

You also have a missing square bracket in your `.find()` query:

Instead of

```
if($(element.form).find("input[type=radio") == true)
```

Try:

```
if($(element.form).find("input[type=radio]").length)
```

---

For what it's worth (quite a lot) you should use the ID selector to target elements by their ID, not the attribute selector. Since you already have the DOM element in a variable, you can just wrap that in a jQuery object:

```
$(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]").addClas...
```

Becomes

```
$(element).addClas...
```

Etc...

Comment: Instead of `$(element.form).find("#" + element.id)`, simply `$(element)` would do.

Comment: @Sparky Right you are. Cheers.

Comment: @Sparky I try to keep the code in my answer as similar to that in the OPs so as not to cause any further potential confusion, but yes, thanks.